# How to translate a QGIS project using a *.qm file? / my QGIS project is not translated?

Tags: qgis, internationalization, qgs

Usually when you create a QGIS project, you will name the attributes, layer etc. in your own language. You might want to deliver the project to another user in another language.

Answer (score 4):

The general workflow and technical details are well explained [here:](https://www.opengis.ch/2018/09/11/qgis-speaks-a-lot-of-languages/)

1. Create a .qgs project file in a base language (e.g. English)
2. Create a .ts translation file for language(s) in QGIS: Project > Properties > General > Generate a translation file
3. Translate the .ts file in Qt Linguist
4. Compile the .ts file to a .qm file using Qt Linguist
5. Name your qm file `project_fr.qm` if you want to translate `project.qgs`
6. In Preferences > Options > General:

- Check "override system locale"
- Set the destination language and local

7. Open `project.qgs`, `project_fr.qgs` is automatically generated.